# Facebook Oauth/Login fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have since two days trouble with a normal login/oauth(orization) via a facebook application.

It behaves as like the app never left Sandbox Mode (which is disabled):
Login Fails for (alot/some/not all) normal users however there's no problem for the page admins, developers etc. to authorize.

There's an error at the oauth page of facebook, not very helpful:
"An error occurred. Please try again later."

I made a stupid test app, that really does not much:

- The app at facebook:
  http://apps.facebook.com/mygeneraltesting/
- The URL of the iframe (no https there): (I'm restricted to two urls in one post, so see it as a comment)
- The minimal possible (IMHO) URL to the Oauth dialog:
  (I'm restricted to two urls in one post, so see it as a comment)

It really seems like the error is caused by facebook, but it is hard to find someone else with this problem online. So I'd like to ask:

- Is anyone else seeing the error message from above?
- Is anybody out there with the same problems on their app?
- If you like to make a code review, (see: http://graphicore.de/downloads/generaltesting.tar.gz ) is there anything suspicious?

Thanks alot, Lasse

(the German errror message for search the engines: "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es später noch einmal.")

Comment: The URL of the iframe (no https there):
http://graphicore.de/generaltesting/

The minimal possible (IMHO) URL to the Oauth dialog:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=313051485420041&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmygeneraltesting%2F

Comment: usually this happens if you put a wrong URL in the application settings in the developers area: http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php make sure you put the corrent url in the website, or app on facebook. local IP address if working on localhost (not the 127.0.01).

Comment: Thanx, dragonjet, but the URL is correct. Did you see the error message or did the authorization work for you?

Comment: yes I saw the error at the auth popup box at times. it seems it is on facebook, but try removing channelURL and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very dated now. The answer is: Facebook made something wrong. The same code worked on another app created some time later (I don't even remember how much later) but never worked on that app, AFAIK. So it was just a broken app on facebook side.